# asp.net mvc areas namespace issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

i have created the area and in that area i am trying to access the IPagedList pagecount property which exist outside the area.but  the pagecount is not accessible. the problem here is that it is accessing in other area created by other person. but not in my area. what i might be doing wrong or what setting i may be missing?

fully qualified name is also not working with the IPagedList

```
Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<IPagedList<SepiaCMS.Areas.KMF.Models.GIS.GIS>>" %>
```

```
<%@ Import Namespace="SepiaCMS.Helpers" %>

 <% if (ViewData.Model.PageCount > 1)  // pagecount not accessible
```

outside the area in helper folder

```
public interface IPagedList<T> : IList<T>
{
    int PageCount { get; }
    int TotalItemCount { get; }
    int PageIndex { get; }
    int PageNumber { get; }
    int PageSize { get; }
    bool HasPreviousPage { get; }
    bool HasNextPage { get; }
    bool IsFirstPage { get; }
    bool IsLastPage { get; }
}
```

Comment: Did you not just ask this same question like half an hour ago.. ?

Comment: ok it might be of same (essense) but i think that was a separate issue

Comment: Well the problem was that the original product is in 2010 mvc2 , i opened it in visual 2012 and by default in that the area is created with web.config version 3. i dont't know why but copy pasting the previous areas web.config in my new area solves the problem. everything is working now.